# Thread guards and function inlining

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have following lock and thread guard implementations:

```
class Spinlock
{
public:
    /* Default constructor/destructor + deleted copy/moving */

    void Lock()
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
            // spin...
        };
    }

    void Unlock()
    {
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag m_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};

template<class ThreadLock>
class ThreadGuard
{
public:
    /* Default constructor + deleted copy/moving */

    /* Constructor */
    ThreadGuard(ThreadLock& lock)
        : m_pLock(&lock)
    {
        m_pLock->Lock();
    }

    /* Destructor */
    ~ThreadGuard()
    {
        m_pLock->Unlock();
    }

private:
    ThreadLock* m_pLock;
};
```

Now, lets say I have following piece of code:

```
void LockDataAndSetX()
{
   ThreadGuard lock(m_spinLock);
   /* ... operations on data here ...*/
}

{
   /* code... */

   LockDataAndSetX();

   /* more code...  */
}
```

I wander, if compiler desides to inline LockDataAndSetX function, would it translate to below code?

```
{
   /* code... */

   ThreadGuard lock(m_spinLock);
   /* ... operations on data here ...*/

   /* more code...  */

}
```

I ask, because that would be problematic for me, because range of lock will depened on compiler inlining/not-inlining lock function. I would need to remove my thread guard class in that case.

Comment: According to this discussion the scope would be preserved even when the function is inlined. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/88491/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope / lifetime of a variable does not depend on inlining. Inlining is an optimization matter and code must have the very same effect independently on whether a compiler applies inlining or not.

You can imagine the effect of inlining more like as follows:

```
{
   /* code... */

   {
      ThreadGuard lock(m_spinLock);
      /* ... operations on data here ...*/
   }

   /* more code...  */
}
```

Note also that `ThreadGuard` is a template and template argument deduction for classes (based on constructor arguments) works from C++17.